# cocoaAsync:udp sendto success but Wireshark can't capture out data

Tags: ios, udp, sendto

I'm using cocoaAsync to handle udp communication.
When i use the sendData API of cocoaAsync ,I'm sure sendto is success,from the log. But I can't see any output data from  Wireshark .

This is not 100% reproducible, but very probably.
I can't figure out what could be the problem.

Thanks very much for any tips.

Comment: do you find any solution? My case is udp packet is sent successfully within 1day51mins43s, and from then on, I can not capture any packet. Dst is multicast ip. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you are sending the packets right then following can be possibilites,

If you are sending and receiving on same machine then it is possible that your Wireshark do not capture. Try sending to some different destination than your machine.

Also there can be multiple network interfaces on your machine (e.g: eth0, eth1 etc...) for Wifi and Network-Card. Please make sure you are capturing packets on the right interface. You can select interface when you press the Capture button on Wireshark.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am sending data through wifi,and I am sure I'm monitor the right interface..... and I send really small udp packets...